# Ruby - Array multiplication or JOIN operation

Tags: ruby, arrays, set

I have two arrays,

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [:a]
```

I want to get the result as

```
[[1, :a], [2, :a]]
```

Is there any methods for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [:a]
a.product(b)
=> [[1, :a], [2, :a]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it this way

```
[a,b*a.size].transpose
#=> [[1, :a], [2, :a]]
```